# Changing to_param yields error in "model"_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.8.

Here's the `to_param` in my `shop` model:

```
  def to_param
    require 'unicode'
    "#{id}-#{Unicode::normalize_KD("-"+name+"-").downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9\s_-]+/,'').gsub(/[\s_-]+/,'-')[0..-2]}".gsub(/-{2,}/,'-')
  end
```

When I tried to change `#{id}-` to `#{id}/` the following:

```
  def to_param
    require 'unicode'
    "#{id}/#{Unicode::normalize_KD("-"+name+"-").downcase.gsub(/[^a-z0-9\s_-]+/,'').gsub(/[\s_-]+/,'-')[0..-2]}".gsub(/-{2,}/,'-')
  end
```

I get the following error in my `index.html.erb`:

```
shop_url failed to generate from {:type=>"places", :action=>"show", :controller=>"shops", :id=>#<shop id: 16, shop_type: "fashion", name: "Shop1", shop_subtype: nil, ...}

Extracted source (around line #54):

51: 
52:               <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
53:                 <div id="<%= dom_id(shop) %>" class="item">
54:                   <a href="<%= shop_path(shop, :type => @type) %>">
55:                     <% if !shop.photos.blank? %>
56:                       <%= image_tag(shop.photos.last.url(:thumb), :class => 'thumbnail') %>
57:                     <% else %>
```

I am trying to change the URL from `shops/12-shop-abc` to `shops/12/shop-abc`. In fact, I am actually trying to change to `shops/shop-abc` using friendly_id, but it fails on both.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` in the name yields the error for normal `to_param`. It's solved with friendly_id.